# Error in INSERT INTO query

Tags: c#, winforms, sql-insert, insert-into

Code is running fine, has connected to the database successfully, however I cannot see where the error is in this INSERT query, can anyone see the error?

```
string SaveUserQuery = "INSERT INTO Employee (PayrollNo, FirstName, LastName, Password, AnnualHolidayEntitlement, DaysTakenToDate, Admin, Department) Values(@PayrollNo, @FirstName, @LastName, @Password, @AnnualHolidayEntitlement, @DaysTakenToDate, @Admin, @Department)";
```

Edit, Added the error.

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException' occurred in System.Data.dll
>
> Additional information: Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement.

Edit, Added how I have added parameters for clarity

```
SaveUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PayrollNo", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = Convert.ToInt32(txtPayrollNo.Text);
SaveUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstName", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = txtFirstName.Text;
SaveUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LastName", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = txtLastName.Text;
SaveUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = "12345";
SaveUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AnnualHolidayEntitlement", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = Convert.ToInt32(TxtAHE.Text);
SaveUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DaysTakenToDate", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = Convert.ToInt32(TxtDTTD.Text);

if (IsAdmin()) { SaveUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Admin", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = "Y"; }
else { SaveUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Admin", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = "N"; }

SaveUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Department", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = cbbDepartment.Text;
```

Comment: Usually helps if you tell us the error.  Password might be a keyword, so I would try placing square brackets around it.

Comment: Have you tried testing the query first from your SQL Server?

Comment: I have never tested a query from the SQL server, I never knew it was an option. @LarsTech Your suggestion of square brackets solved my problem, thank you very much, would you post it as an answer?

Comment: It would be useful to see the code that inserts the parameters into this query, ready for sending to the database. They may need to be wrapped with quotes for strings, or it could be a reserved word, or some other data entry issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, I think you got some key words that need to be in brackets to tell sql its a field.

```
INSERT INTO Employee (PayrollNo, FirstName, LastName, [Password], AnnualHolidayEntitlement, DaysTakenToDate, [Admin], Department) Values(@PayrollNo, @FirstName, @LastName, @Password, @AnnualHolidayEntitlement, @DaysTakenToDate, @Admin, @Department)
```